# Sql JOIN request issue

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have got 2 tables.

**A :**

```
ida   title    
1    aaa
2    bbb
3    ccc
```

and 
**B :**

```
idb    ida    date                   count
1      1      2014-09-15 14:22:37    15
2      1      2014-09-15 15:52:07    34
3      1      2014-09-15 14:25:38    16
```

I would like to get all the A table rows, the most recent date and the count corresponding in **B** even if none of them exist in B table.

I expect this result on this example.

```
A.ida   A.title  B.date                B.count  
1       aaa      2014-09-15 15:52:07   34
2       bbb      null                  null
3       ccc      null                  null
```

Any help would be apreciated :)

Edit : my initial and false request was :

```
SELECT e.ida, MAX(n.date_add) as date_notification, n.count FROM ida e LEFT JOIN idb n ON e.ida =  n.ida group by e.ida
```

Don't joining it to this initial Stack was akward.

Comment: Any effort would be appreciated too.

Comment: i would use a derived table followed by an outer join if you need some prompting

Comment: Did you try something before asking your question?

Comment: did not wanted to join all my requests to this Stack :) all of mine do not work :/

Comment: Of course I did :) my Stack was ackward see my edit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT A.ida
    ,A.title
    ,B.date
    ,B.count
FROM tableA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT B.ida
                      ,MAX(B.date) AS [max_date]
                FROM tableB B
                GROUP BY B.ida) T ON T.ida = A.ida
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB B ON B.ida = T.ida
                           AND B.date = T.max_date
ORDER BY A.ida
```

The first jointure is used to get only the last date for each `ida` and the second jointure is used to get the corresponding information from `tableB`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, was missing this second left Join !

Comment: It's a pleasure to help